# Passing a tabelview indexPath.row as String to VC WebView

Tags: objective-c, swift, tableview

I have a TableViewController which I am attempting to pass through a URL to a WebView on another ViewController

I am overriding the below function, which works find if I make the URL static as you can see in the comment out `let newsLink` constant

```
let newsLink = "http://www.stuff.co.nz/business/industries/69108799/Kirkcaldie-Stains-department-store-to-become-David-Jones"
```

However with the below pulling the `URL` from `indexPath.row` it fails for some reason and passes through a `nil` value

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        let newsLink = (posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("link") as! String)
        //let newsLink = "http://www.stuff.co.nz/business/industries/69108799/Kirkcaldie-Stains-department-store-to-become-David-Jones"
        println(newsLink)

        let newsWebViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idNewsWebViewController") as! NewsWebViewController

        newsWebViewController.newsURL = NSURL(string: newsLink)

        showDetailViewController(newsWebViewController, sender: self)

    }
```

If I println() the below, I get exactly the same output as the `URL` I ahve hardcoded in the test `let newsLink` constant

```
println(posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("link") as! String)
```

I can't figure out why this is failing. Hopefully someone smarter than me can help.

The code on the receiving end VC is below"

```
var newsURL : NSURL!
    //var newsURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.co.nz")

    @IBOutlet weak var newsWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descTextView: UITextView!
```

and in the viewDidAppear function

```
let request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: newsURL!)
```

newsWebView.loadRequest(request)

More Info

var types

```
var posts = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
```

how I am adding objects

```
elements.setObject(urlLink, forKey: "link")
posts.addObject(elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the declaration / structure of the "posts" variable?

Without more information, the only thing I can think of is that the value of "link" is not actually a String, but something (maybe a NSURL) that when printed shows that content. That would explain the println showing the same url but the cast failing.

When you print, or implicitly convert any object to a String (as in the println), it calls the "description" method of that object.

For example:

```
class MyURLContainer {
  var link:String

  override func description() -> String {
    return link
  }
}


let url = MyURLContainer()
let url.link = "http://www.example.com"
println( "my link: \(url)" ) // this would show the link correctly
let link = url as? String // this will be nil, as url can't be casted to String
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `(posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("link")` does not return a `String` type. It might already be a NSURL, and hence showing you correct value in `println()`

Could you post some more details about it. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was the encoding on the URL that NSURL didn't like.

The solution was to use the below:

```
var escapedString = originalString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

I'm new to swift, but this seems a bit messy.